# Aggregate data by index and column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, aggregate-functions

I have a stock price data like this. The date is actually the dataframe's index. Rest are columns.

```
date         open    high    low    close  name
2013-01-01   14.50   14.80   14.25  14.70  AAA
2013-01-02   14.70   14.90   14.30  14.68  AAA
2013-01-01   14.50   14.80   14.25  14.70  BBB
2013-01-02   14.70   14.90   14.30  14.68  BBB
2013-01-01   14.50   14.80   14.25  14.70  CCC
2013-01-02   14.70   14.90   14.30  14.68  CCC
```

I want a new dataframe that has the averages of open, high, low and close values by month by each unique name.

Best I could get was using this code but without the 'name' column.

```
stock_agg = {
  'open': {'ave_open': 'mean'},
  'high': {'ave_high': 'mean'},
  'low': {'ave_low': 'mean'},
  'close': {'ave_close': 'mean'}
}
stock_group = stock_data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M')]).agg(stock_agg)
```

How do I group by name and month in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby` can handle multiple `by`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby([df.index.month, 'name']).mean()
```

Output:

```
           open   high     low  close
date name                            
1    AAA   14.6  14.85  14.275  14.69
     BBB   14.6  14.85  14.275  14.69
     CCC   14.6  14.85  14.275  14.69
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. This aggregates well. But I do not want the date to be in `datetime` format and not convert it as an integer like 1, 2 etc. Is that possible?

Comment: I meant I want the date to be in datetime format and not an integer like 1, 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second level in `groupby`:

```
stock_group = stock_data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'name']).agg(stock_agg)
```

Comment: Thanks Serge. I did add 'name' to my groupby earlier. But the month and the stock name become part of the df index. I want to plot selective stocks by month. Didn't know how to do that. For example I cannot do this: `stock_group[stock_group.name=='AAA]` when name is part of index. Can I?

Comment: @python_beginner You should say what is the expected result.

Comment: My apologies. I will be clear from next time onwards with my end goal or expected result.